# python trouble de-serializing avro in memory

Tags: python, python-requests, avro

Currently, I am using requests to grab an avro file from a database and storing the data in requests.text. the file is separated by the schema and data. How do I merge the schema and data in memory into readable/usable data.

Requests.text brings the data down in Unicode, and seperates it by schema first and data second. I have been able to use string manipulation to just grab the schema part of the Unicode and set that as a schema variable, however I am unsure how to handle the data section. I tried encodeing the data to utf-8 and passing it as raw_bytes in my code, with no luck,

```py
#the request text is too large, so I am shortening it down
r.text = u'Obj\x01\x04\x14avro.codec\x08null\x16avro.schema\u02c6\xfa\x05{"namespace": "namespace", "type": "record", "fields" : [{"type": ["float", "null"], "default": " ", "name": "pvib_z_crest_factor"}], 

#repeat for x amount of fields

"name": "Telemetry"}\x00\u201d \xe0B\x1a\u2030=\xc0\u01782\n.\u015e\x049\xaa\x12\xf6\u2030\x02\x00\u0131\u201a];\x02\x02\x02\x00\xed\r>;\x02\x02\x00\x01\x02\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x02\x00\x00\x00\x1aC\x00\x00\x00\x02C\x02\x00:\x00@2019-02-27 16:38:39.530263-05:00\x02\x02\x00\xaeGa=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf8\x04\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x02\x02\x02\x00\xac\xc5\'7\x00\x00\x00\xe9B\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e-r@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x02\x00\xfa\xc0\xf5A\x00\x00\x00\xc0@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x02\xc9\xebB\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xaa\ufffd\'\x02\x00\x02\xc9\xebB\x02\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\ufffd\xc2u=\x02\x00\xfc\x18\xd3>\x02\x02\x00\\\ufffdB>\x02\x02\x001\x08,=\x02\x00\x00\x02\x02\x00\x000oE\x00sh!A\x02\x00\x00\xc0uE\x02\x00\xf6(tA\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\xb2\ufffd=\x02\x00\x1c \xd1B\x02\x02\x00@2019-02-27 16:38:39.529977-05:00\x02\x00\x080894\x00\u011f\xa7\xc6=\x00\x00\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x00\x00\x00\xe0A\x02\x00\x00\x00\u011eA\x00\x00\x00\xb8A\x00\xc3\xf5\xc0@\x00\xd5x\xe9=\x02\x00\x00\x00q=VA\x02\x00\x00\x000B\x02\x00ZV\xfaE\x02\x02\x02\x02\x00\x00\x00!C\x02\x00\x00\x00#C\x00\x00\x00)C\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\u20ac?\x00\x00\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x00\xf8\x04\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\u20ac?\x00\x02W\x00ff6A\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\xcc&\x10L\x00\x00\xf7\x7fG\x02\x02\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x02\x02\x00\x00\u20ac\xacC\x02\x02\x02\x00\x1c~%A\x00\x1c \xd1B\x00\x01\x02\x02\x02\x00\xfa\xc0\xf5A\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x00\x00\x000B\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?C\x00\xf4-\x1fE\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\u0131\x7fG\x00\x00\u015f\x7fG\x00\x00\u0131\x7fG\x00\x00\x00\x0bC\x00@2019-05-31 13:00:25.931949+00:00\x00@2019-05-31 09:00:25.931967-04:00\x00\x00\x00\xe0A\x00h\xe8\u0178:\x00=\n%C\x00\x00\x00\x07C\x02\x00\x00\x00\xe0@\x00\x01\x02\x00\x00\x02\x02\x00\x00\u011e\u2020F\x02\x00\x00\u20acDE\x00\xcd\xcc\xcc=\x00@2019-02-27 16:38:39.529620-05:00\x02\x00\x00\x00\xc8B\x00\x00\x00\x06C\x02\x00\x01\x004\u20ac7:\x00\x00\x000B\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x0033CA\x02\x00L7\t>\x02\x02\x00\xae\xc7\xa7B\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x02\x02\x00\x00\x00pB\x00\x00\x00`B\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00...
#continues on, too big to put the rest of (feel free to ask questions to see more)
```

I except the file in memory to be de-serialized into readable data, however I have been getting constant errors of list being out of range or cannot access branch index x.

Thank you for reading

EDIT(6/5/19):

I managed to download the avro file using azure storage explorer on another device. From here, I ran the following code:

```py
import avro.schema
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter


avro_file = DataFileReader(open("Destination/to/file.avro", "rb"), DatumReader())
avro_file = [x for x in avro_file]
for i in range(len(avro_file)):
    print(len(data))
    print(data[i])
```

(NOTE: the computer I ran this code on runs off of python 3.7, but theres no real syntax changes between the two python version)

This code runs smoothly and shows the data in the appropriate places.
 However, Cannot simply pass the same data im recieving from the request as an argument to DataFileReader (Stating the obvious, but guessing it has something to do with calling "rb" when opening the file and the request.text being in unicode). Is their any way to modify that request.text to work so I can pass it as an argument inside DataFileReader (replacing open(file, "rb"))?

Comment: Well, you don't want utf-8 data. You want to keep it as bytes type... What avro library are you using?

Comment: slr ive been sick for the past few days. Currently I am using the python avro library for avro.schema (turn the fist half of the avro file, that being the schema, into a schema object), avro.io (for datumReader) and io (for BytesIO, thinking that's what I call on the data portion of the avro file). If it helps I am still running on python 2.7 while I am still trying to update everything to python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `content`, not `text`

I also think you'll want to try BytesIO, which should be able to be used like a file object

```
import io
import requests

r = requests.get("http://example.com/file.avro")
inmemoryfile = io.BytesIO(r.content)

reader = DataFileReader(inmemoryfile, DatumReader())
records = list(reader)
reader.close()
```

(code untested)

Comment: Switching it to content was definitely the trick, I should've read up more on the requests library instead of assuming text was the way to go. Thank you so much!